# What is a good way to determine a server's connection usage?

Tags: connection, netstat, resources, resource-management

Trying to figure out where my system's connections are being used (i.e. how many connections belong to what processes - could even be filtered by some expression through `grep`, if it applies).  The system is running CentOS 6.

How can I determine what the connection usage is for a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `netstat` command is what you are looking for:

```sh
$ netstat --all --programs --tcp --udp
```

Comment: Excellent!  Running  `netstat --all --programs --tcp --udp | grep postgres | wc -l` gives me all the PostgreSQL connections on that server, which is what I was looking for.  Thanks!